# How do I get meaning out of the clusters that I got using K-means?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-analysis

So I am working on a project related to the clustering of ships based on the parameters like - ship length, ship id, ship gross tonnage, ship engine power, ship name, and ship municipality code. Based on these 7 features I performed kmeans clustering and got the following clusters. [kmeans clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0DBK.png)

I cannot apply hierarchical clustering because there a million data points. The main question is how do i get information/inference out of these clusters. Like larger ships having less gross tonnage were from these municipality code/areas or something like that.

I am attaching the notebook link (github) : [ntbk_link](https://github.com/mrinalyadav7-atom/Catch_data_clustering)

If someone could answer it would be of great help.

Thank you

Comment: Not a good idea to shout the title

Comment: Your question is too open-ended for Stack Overflow. It is more of a statistical methodology question than a programming question. [statistics.se] would be a better place to ask (though read their version of [ask] -- something that you seem to have not done prior to asking here).

Comment: i was thinking of plotting each of the numeric feature for each cluster to see how they vary in different clusters . Is it a good idea to analyze the clusters?